# Running a query and extract simultaneously in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

If I want to run a BQ query and extract the resulting table to GCS, is it safe to do the query insert and then immediately kick off the extract job, or do I have to wait for the query job to complete?

Answer (score 2):

The extract job will begin immediately and will extract the table as of the time that job starts. If that table doesn't exist yet because you're doing an insert to the table simultaneously, than the extract will fail.